# Ideal of finite intersection of algebraic sets

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In general if $X_1$ and $X_2$ are two algebraic sets on $k^n$ with $k$ a field of characteristic zero, we have that $I( X_1 \cap X_2 ) = \sqrt{ I(X_1) + I(X_2) }.$
Is posible in general compute $I(X_1 \cap X_2 \cap \dots \cap X_n)$ in terms of $I(X_1), \dots , I(x_n)$?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you assume characteristic 0? This is not necessary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remember that for any ring $R$ and ideal $J\subseteq R$,
$$\sqrt{J}=\bigcap_{\large\substack{\text{prime ideals}\\ P\supseteq J}} \!\!\!\!\!\!\!P.$$
Also, remember that for ideals $J_1,J_2,J_3\subseteq R$, we have
$$J_1\supseteq J_2+J_3\iff J_1\supseteq J_2\quad\text{and}\quad J_1\supseteq J_3.$$
Use this to show that for any ideals $J_1,J_2$ of $R$,
$$\sqrt{J_1+\sqrt{J_2}}=\sqrt{J_1+J_2}$$
so that you can use induction to prove what you want.

Comment: Using prime ideals is a total overkill :).

Answer (score 7):

In general we have $\sqrt{I+\sqrt{J}}=\sqrt{I+J}$, since both ideals are the smallest radical ideals containing $I$ and $J$. It follows by induction that $I(X_1 \cap \dotsc \cap X_n)=\sqrt{I(X_1) + \dotsc + I(X_n)}$.